# DNF or CNF functions

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

The problem tells us to find the full DNF and CNF of the logic function $f(P, Q, R)$ = True if and only if either Q is True or R is False.

I feel fine with converting to get the full DNF or CNF form, I guess my problem is the form at which I am given. Usually we are given a function right off the bat like, (A $\land$ B) $\lor$ C or something nice like that. But here, I am given "True iff Q is True or R is False."

So since Q is true and R is False, would it be (Q $\lor$ $\lnot$ R) $\land$ P? I am confused on what to do with P since the problem does not mention it, but it's apart of the function. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

No, if you include $\wedge P$, that makes it require $P$ to be true as well.  The proper logic is $Q \vee \neg R$ (provided that the OR is not exclusive-OR).

Comment: That's what confuses me. What do I do with P then? The logic function is f(P, Q, R) so can I leave P out? How would I do a DNF of $Q \lor \lnot R$ then? Since I am missing P would I add the value in by doing: $(Q \lor \lnot R) \land True$ where True is $(P \lor \lnot P)$?

Comment: Unless you're being required in some way to include $P$, you don't have to include it.  For instance, $f(x, y) = x$ is still a function of $x$ and $y$; it's just constant with respect to $y$.  If you prefer, you can think of the DNF form as $(Q \wedge \text{True}) \vee (\neg R \wedge \text{True})$; the CNF form as $(Q \vee \neg R) \wedge (\text{True})$, "True" being the empty conjunction.

Comment: We are required to include P. So if I include P, I get:  

$(P \land (Q \lor \lnot R)) \lor (\lnot P \land (Q \lor \lnot R))$ which is correct, isn't? I just ask because I am getting a really long answer which is making me second guess myself.

Here is what I got for the complete answer:

$(P \land Q \land R) \lor(P \land Q \land \lnot R) \lor (P \land \lnot Q \land \lnot R) \lor (\lnot P \land Q \land R) \lor (\lnot P \land Q \land \lnot R) \lor (\lnot P \land \lnot Q \land \lnot R)$